# Shipping applications in servers to clients

Tags: software

More than half of the applications I make for clients require a server setup with apache and mysql.
What is the easiest way of shipping a server so that the billing of the server goes to them or so that they can set the server up locally/ in their own server if they want to?

Comment: I'm not certain if this is really a freelance question. It seems to be a more logistics question. Perhaps better answered at http://StackOverflow.com (but that's just my guess).

Comment: Very closely related: http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/2022/how-to-setup-client-ownership-of-domain-name-and-hosting/2023#2023

Answer (score 1):

#### VPS

There are various solutions to this (*"shipping a server with the setup"*). The one I predominantly use is a VPS solution where:

- I set up the VPS server through a host. Usually with the following:

  - Ubuntu/CentOS (or another flavour of *nix), maybe even Windows if required
  - Apache/Nginx (Web Server)
  - PHP & SQL

With the particular host I use, I was allowed to take a snapshot of a base server that allows me to simply deploy a server with selected resources - harnessing that setup (Exactly what you want as a server setup). From here, I simply bill the client appropriately. Keeping in mind the potential maintenance that you may need to carry out on the server could also/should also carry a surcharge.

---

#### Recommending Hosting

Alternatively - you could recommend hosting to a customer, listen out the pros & cons between them will also help keep the customer satisfied. From here - let them purchase the hosting - guiding them through the process is a **must**! Ensuring everything they select/input is correct and adequate enough to run the applications you design.

Research for this isn't necessarily required, but can go a long way in the clients eyes. There is no shortage of hosts, so the choice is yours!

> #### Note
>
> One thing to note; Shared hosting isn't always the best solution. Users are thrown onto overcrowded boxes which is highly evident in performance.

This is usually why I sway customers from shared hosting to VPS hosting where we are in complete control. Along with a comparable pricing model.