# Hosting management should be on the name of who? Customer's or our?

Tags: billing

As a freelancer web designer should handle with the hosting management of a customer's site?

When we manage it the *hosting plan contract* should be on the *customer's name* or *on our one*?

If the hosting plan contract's on my name I can suffer the risk of the customer at some moment not to pay the hosting plan value causing problems with the hosting provider.

How *avoid* it? How you handle with that situation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to setup client ownership of domain name and hosting](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/2022/how-to-setup-client-ownership-of-domain-name-and-hosting) -- After years of experience, I choose **not** to do anything but *recommend* a hosting provider to clients. They are responsible for paying for it and merely sending me FTP access.